# C++ template of templated typename

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I need to use a third party templated function like this:

```cpp
template<typename...Types>
void third_party_func(){}
```

I will call it like this:

```cpp
third_party_func<type_1, const type_2>();
```

and I would like to capture that types somehow. So my idea is to wrap it to another function
and with help of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to capture that types.

```cpp
template<typename Funct>
void registerFunct(Funct funct)
{
    // parse __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    funct();
}
```

when I call it like this:

```cpp
registerFunct(third_party_func<type_1, const type_2>);
```

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` does not capture `type_1, const type_2`. So I tried something else
and hope that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` will now be able to capture what I want:

```cpp
template<template<typename...FunctParams>typename Funct>
void registerFunct(Funct funct){}
```

produces an error: argument list for template template parameter is missing...

```cpp
template<template<typename...FunctParams>typename Funct>
void registerFunct(Funct<> funct){}
```

compiles itself, but when add actual function call then does not compile that function call...

```cpp
template<template<typename...FunctParams>typename Funct>
void registerFunct(Funct<FunctParams...> funct){}
```

produces an error: identifier FunctParams is undefined...

so right now I am out of ideas how to do that properly...

Comment: "_and I would like to capture that types somehow._": What exactly do you mean here? What do you intent to do with the result? Also, what type are you talking about? The only types are `type_1` and `const type_2`, which you provided yourself. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in GCC/Clang gives you the name of the function, not of a type. There is no standardized way to obtain the name of a type or function.

Comment: *"I would like to capture that types somehow..."* That's what you already did by having a template type parameter `Types`. All types are already there.

Comment: code `template<typename... Types>
void testFunct()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}` will produce output `void testFunct() [with Types = {int, const double}]` so I can extract the types from there and I want to use it to make `signature` because `<const type1, type2>` and `<type2, const type1>` is the same for me - I want to separate the read-only and read-write types without code repetition...

Comment: "_and I want to use it to make signature_": What does that mean? You don't need to parse any types. You already have the types (and their `const`-qualifier) at the call site. Even if you could parse types, you can't reify a types name as a string into the type. To check whether a type is `const`-qualified you only need `std::is_const_v`. Checking whether the template arguments fully intersect as sets is also possible with just template code. I'd recommend you show what code duplication you are trying to avoid in a [mre] instead of asking to implement a flawed attempt at a solution.

Comment: whats wrong with `template <typename ...T> void registerFunc() { /*do whatever you like with T... */ third_party_func<T...>(); }` ? You dont need a template template argument when you want to instantiate always the same function template

Comment: What do you want to do with captured types?

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI I want to build a `map`, where key=type(in form of string or hashed string) and value=bool whether it is const or not. @463035818_is_not_an_ai actually that third_party_function is running in a loop and I need to extract that types just once out of that loop. So `registerFunc` takes that as argument, extract the types and does not run it. At least I am interested in what is the usage of the code: `template<template<typename...FunctParams>typename Funct>` How should declaration of function which follows looks like?

Comment: You can use typeid(funct).name() and demangle it.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI this `typeid(third_party_funct<double, double>()).name()` returns just `void` and this `typeid(third_party_funct<double, double>).name()` returns `void __cdecl(void)`

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, template parameters are not a part of the type of the function. IMHO this is not really possible unless you pass the types separately to `registerFunct`.